# Java wildcard generic, not getting error on <? super String> but otherwise the error is "cannot be applied to Java.lang.String"

Tags: java, generics, functional-programming, wildcard

While trying out a piece of code using generics, wildcard and functional programming, I have a doubt, A simple program below

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x = "";
    String y = getFormData().apply(x);
}

private static Function<?, String> getFormData() {
    return x -> ((String) x).concat("asd");
}
```

The above program throws an error on the line

```
String y = getFormData().apply(x);
```

> `apply (capture<?>)` in `Function` cannot be applied to (`java.lang.String`)

But if I change the getFormData() function to

```
private static Function<? super String, String> getFormData() {
    return x -> ((String) x).concat("asd");
}
```

the error is gone.

Can somebody explain why this is happening ? I know `<? super String>` means, any super type of String or String itself.

Comment: The first version of your method `getFormData()` could return a `Function<Integer, String>`. This function then clearly cannot be applied to a `String`! In the second case however `getFormData()` is not allowed to return a `Function<Integer, String>`.

Answer (score 2):

The first version of your method:

```
    Function<?, String> getFormData() {...}
```

could return a `Function<Integer, String>`. This function then clearly cannot be applied to a `String`!

In the second case however:

```
    Function<? super String, String> getFormData() {...}
```

it is not allowed to return a `Function<Integer, String>`.

Answer (score 0):

The type expression `Function<?, String>` is compatible with any `Function` that returns `String`, regardless of its argument type.  For example, it is compatible with a `Function<Integer, String>`.  Therefore, if you have no more specific information about it than that then you cannot safely pass a `String` -- *or anything else* -- as the argument to its `apply` method.  The type expression does not provide enough information to determine what argument types are allowed.

On the other hand, the type expression `Function<? super String, String>` is compatible only with `Function`s that accept `String` or one of its supertypes as an argument (and return `String`).  It is always safe to apply such a function to a `String`.  It would also be safe to apply it to an instance of a subclass of `String` if it were possible to create such a subclass.  It is not safe to apply it to any other type, however, not even a strict supertype of `String`, because the first type parameter of the `Function` could always be `String` itself.

Overall, since that means the only acceptable argument type is `String`, you don't appear to gain anything but confusion from using a wildcard.  I'd just use `Function<String, String>` instead.